# Rescale UIImageView proprtionally in Launch Screen Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, launch-screen

I have a `UIImageView` that needs to be centered and have a width that's equal to the screen width and some height that grows proportionally with the width. So for instance, for the iPhoneXR I have:

[image]

And on the iPad 9.7 it would be:

[image]

So basically the image just scales proportionally with each screen size. I have already figured out how to center it using constraints, but I'm lost on how to get it to scale proportionally. I've played around with the auto resizing options and constraints to no avail. I struggle so badly with these storyboards, wish I could just code it! Is this even possible in a LaunchScreen storyboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't execute any code inside launch screen. However, you can make it with constraints.

---

Set center equal to `superview`, then set `width` equal to `superview`. Now, you can add `aspectRatio` which is like `1:1`, so you imageView `height` would always be equal to its width or any other ratio you want.

**Example:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How did you get those 1:1 ratio and equal width to appear? I can't get those from the standard menu.

Comment: Press and hold `ctrl` now drag from `imageView` to itself and select aspect ratio https://ibb.co/SmRqfnF

Comment: Really appreciate it! One last question if you don't mind, I was able to get mine to say "Equal Width to: safe area" which gets the job done, but was unable to get it for the superview. How did you accomplish that? When I dragged from UIImageView to the UIViewController view, it didn't give me an option to do equal widths to.

Comment: @NSMoron Select your constraint, then click twice and you will see its setting, here you can change second item from safeArea to Superview https://ibb.co/k2zcSDd

Answer (score 1):

By adding proper constraint you will get your expected result. Add `aspectRatio` constraint to `imageView`.

[image]

All constraints as per

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Was there something else you did? I've tried that option and it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can not give constraints to a view w.r.t viewController in LaunchScreen.storyboard because our view hierarchy has not loaded till that point of time.
You can give an imageView constraints w.r.t itself. CTRL drag on the imageView and select height, width or aspect ratio.

Though the recommended way will be to use another viewController that will work as  LaunchScreen with some delay in segue.